# I reserve or I am reserving

Tags: present-simple

I  found a very rare book on the internet. I had been looking for it for a long time . I emailed the seller and he answered "OK I **am reserving** it for you or I **reserve** it for you".

I think the first one could imply that the reservation could be limited to a certain amount of time  but I am not sure  or may be both mean the same.

Comment: "I reserve it for you" is not idiomatic. :"I am reserving" or "I will reserve".  Simple present would refer to a habitual or regular practice:  "Do you reserve books for would-be buyers if they do not send you a downpayment? -- Yes, I reserve books for them without requiring a downpayment"

Comment: Well, any reservation will probably be limited in time - they're not going to keep it forever. But I wouldn't worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

The second is oddly expressed, but the first is what you want to hear - the seller is reserving the book for you; (s)he will not sell it to another person.

The statement contains no implication about how long the reservation is for, but normally one would expect a reservation to be only for a limited amount of time.